# how to find a record between two values

Tags: mysql

I have the following [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSWaz.jpg) where there are two relevant fields for searching, this is 'from' and 'to' and represents the range of employees and then the field 'InitialQMSDays' represents the value that I want to return.

So if I have a search value of say 6, it would look at that value and find it between the 6 - 10 row, and return 2.

any ideas?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT InitialQMSDays
  FROM my_table
 WHERE 6 BETWEEN `From` AND `To`;
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As are answers. Note that `from` is a reserved word, as is `to`

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, corrected.